# How to add fragment into inflated view?

Tags: android, view, fragment

I have inflated view like this,
`val view = LayoutInflater.from(this.requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_guidelines_photo, null)` 
this view will be displayed in a custom dialog.

How can I add the whole fragment inside this view?

Answer (score 0):

Add `FrameLayout` in layout_guidelines_photo and then add/replace fragment. make sure you use `getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()..`

Comment: that works for activity. But I am trying to add in inflated View which is not attached to root.